# Unable to autoscale K8s pods using Kapacitor

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kapacitor

Following the setup and install as described here 
https://github.com/influxdata/k8s-kapacitor-autoscale

Below is the ramp.sh output

[image: Below is the ramp.sh output]

The output of curl $APP_URL is "Current request count 4859821" 
The output of curl $KAPACITOR_URL is {"error": "Not Found"} 
At this point I should see 28 pods but I still see the 1 single pod that I started with.

Please help and let me know if there is anything I should look at.

Comment: Also tried all of the same on a mac by running "hey" in docker like so : <br> https://simonwillison.net/2017/Nov/5/golang-docker-for-mac/

Comment: The `$KAPACITOR_URL` is OK `{"error": "Not Found"}` because it is an API endpoint and it requires parameters in JSON format to run. It is not URL to page with HTML structure, and it does return anything if parameters are not applied.